# Insert Icon class to a each div with different ID

Tags: jquery

I have the below Code

```
`<div id="55"> 
    <span class="icon-style">
        <i class=""> </i>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="56"> 
    <span class="icon-style">
        <i class=""> </i>
    </span>
</div>


<div id="57"> 
    <span class="icon-style">
        <i class=""> </i>
    </span>
</div>


<div id="58"> 
    <span class="icon-style">
        <i class=""> </i>
    </span>
</div>

`
```

I need to insert the Icon class (Ex: far fa-smile) from Jquery in the  class. I have access to the div id. Using div id I need to insert it.

For each id, I have different icons, which I need to dynamically tie it using jquery. I have access to the id like 55,56,57,58...I need to add icon class for each div based on the id.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You could make an array of objects e.g. `[{ id: 56, iconClass: 'far fa-smile' },... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#55 span i").addClass("fa-simple")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`<div id="55">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="56">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>


<div id="57">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>


<div id="58">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>

`
```

You can also create an array with the div `id` and the `icon classname` and add the class dynamically.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 
  var icon_list = [{
  id: 55,
  iconClass: 'fa-simple1'
  },
  {
  id: 56,
  iconClass: 'fa-simple2'
  },
  {
  id: 57,
  iconClass: 'fa-simple3'
  },
  {
  id: 58,
  iconClass: 'fa-simple4'
  }]
  
  for(let i=0; i<icon_list.length; i++){
   $("#"+ icon_list[i]['id'] +" span i").addClass(icon_list[i]['iconClass'])
}


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

`<div id="55">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="56">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>


<div id="57">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>


<div id="58">
  <span class="icon-style">
    <i class=""> </i>
  </span>
</div>

`
```

Hope it helps :)